# Changes in header.php not reflecting

Tags: php, parent-theme

I edited `<meta name="author" content="my_new_value">` in `header.php` of the parent theme.

But the same old value is displayed.

I've tried switching themes but this didn't work.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: i mean the changes made to `wordpress > wp-content > themes > parent_theme > header.php` is not seen in the browser